# BeautifulSoup and Selenium sometimes return None even when element is definitely there

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, dynamic, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the Risks and Challenges sections of Kickstarter projects. I have the following code:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get('https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapmaker/snapmaker-20-modular-3-in-1-3d-printers')
html = wd.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
project = soup.find("p", {"class" :"js-risks-text"})
```

However, sometimes it returns None. Is there a way that guarantees actually grabbing what is there?

Comment: The <p>  element actually has nothing as per the link you mentioned https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/41326882/the-vault?ref=category_newest . Can you please elaborate your problem.

Comment: Oh sorry I chose a random link and that happened to actually be empty. However, in cases where there are, like this link https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapmaker/snapmaker-20-modular-3-in-1-3d-printers , sometimes project is None and sometimes it returns the text.

Answer (score 0):

Page is loaded dynamically via `JavaScript` once the page load complete then it's got rendered via `JS`. therefor `requests` module will not be able render `JS` on the fly.

`Selenium` will be good option for now:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get(
    "https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/snapmaker/snapmaker-20-modular-3-in-1-3d-printers")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

risk = soup.find("p", class_="js-risks-text text-preline").text
print(risk)
driver.quit()
```

output:

```
This is our second Kickstarter campaign. To date, we have delivered over 10,000 units to users in over 100 countries. We are using the same supply base that we established over the past two years through our first product. And we continue to improve our production process and technics process. We’ve also selected the best 
suppliers in this industry. We feel confident that we will ensure product quality and hit the delivery dates we are providing.

The Snapmaker 2.0 is a more complex product than the original model. There could 
be unexpected risks that can arise during the pilot production. The safety class 
of the laser module in Snapmaker 2.0 is class 4. We will pay special attention to get FDA/FCC/CE/RoHS certifications in late August, which are necessaries for delivering our products to the US, EU and most areas in the world. When we fulfilled our first Kickstarter campaign, we experienced the hard decision of delaying the mass-production to hold ourselves to high quality and user experience standards. We won’t ship unless our product can meet or exceed these high standards.
```